# I built my app with SD images, how can I support HD?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

What would be the best advice if I have my app built with SD images but I want it to look decent on iphone devices that support HD?

I've heard that simply doubling the size of all my images to get HD versions using Photoshop doesn't look good?

If I just don't support HD at all (turn retina display off in cocos2d) will it look blurred?

Comment: Mh you've heard that halving the resolution (instead of taking 1/4th) of your original full size images will not look good for any image whatsoever on the double res screen. Have you even tried? Of course doubling the resolution of a low res image will look worse afterwards...

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, is this offering a solution? Why would I expect a doubled SD image to look bad on an HD device? HD images are twice the size of SD images.

Comment: Yeah but the thing is: When reducing the resolution, you use interpolation to hide that you've dropped information - thats ok. When you increase resolution, you have to generate information where you didn't have one in the first place, so you are generating values from what you have and that usually looks worse that your original image. Look for the terms "entropy" and "interpolation" and "image processing" on Google to get some mathematical background on this. A simple hands on test: start an iPhone App on your iPad and hit the "x2" button ;)

Comment: Ok thanks, so in my case the best solution is to simply not support retina display?

Comment: Well if you have the original images and they have a high resolution, you can simply create high res versions of them. If you don't have them and you would have to increase the image size from what you have you will have to decide on a per image basis if increasing the resolution looks good or not. If not, it's better to keep the low res version.

Comment: Ok now I'm confused again :/ Isn't increasing the image size what I said originally? And how would I create a high res version? High res or high def? Wow I'm confused... Plus if I turned retina display off it would just look fine in SD anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two types of source images: the raw graphics files you used to create your images, such as a Photoshop or Illustrator file, and then the actual images you exported from those programs to include in your app.

For example, you might take a 10 megapixel photo with a digital camera, but you size it down to include it in your app.

You do not want to increase the size/resolution of the pictures you exported for the app, because they do not have the graphic information to fill a higher image. It's like take a cup of water and expecting it to fill a bucket. The information is simply not there and it will look bad.

However, if you go back to your original graphics files, such as the 10 megapixel image in my example, you can create a new set of exported graphics for the higher resolution. You always start with your raw source files and then go down from there. Never start with files already exported for a certain resolution and then try to go up from there, or you will have pixelated poor graphics as the result.